# Docker build - version of npm is incompatible with lockfileVersion@1

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to make a build a Docker image of a react application.

Here is the first part of the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "eslint": "^7.29.0",
    "html-react-parser": "^1.2.7",
    "npm": "^6.14.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-input-mask": "^3.0.0-alpha.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
```

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

ARG REACT_APP_BASEURL='https://localhost:8081'
ENV REACT_APP_BASEURL=$REACT_APP_BASEURL

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

# add app
COPY . ./

#EXPOSE
EXPOSE 3000

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

So, I build with the command line:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t api_front .
```

and I've this error message:

> npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with
> lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for
> lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!

If I check the version of npm with `npm -v` , I've the latest one (7.19.1)

If I go to the project folder and I run `npm install` , everything is up-to-date

If I start the application with `npm start` , everything is ok and the api is running...

What is the problem?

**Edit: SOLUTION**

I've changed:

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine
```

to

```
FROM node:latest
```

Comment: I've just checked and npm v6.14.4 is installed in that image, so where are you getting 7.19.1 from? Your local system? Then it's not being used and is therefore not relevant.

Comment: You'll need parity between environments. `npm install -g npm@whateverversion` will install a different version of npm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The version of npm (v7.19.1) used to generate the `package-lock.json` file is newer than the version of npm (v6.14.4) inside the docker image of [node 13.12.0](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/).

```
1: The lockfile version used by npm v5 and v6.
2: The lockfile version used by npm v7, which is backwards compatible to v1 lockfiles.
```

You can read more about lockfile versions [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-lock-json#lockfileversion)

You can either upgrade the docker image to use the lastest version or downgrade your npm to generate a compatible `package-lock.json`

EDIT #1:

You have to replace the first line of your docker file with:

```
FROM node:16.4.2
```

Comment: Oh, Thanks for this very interesting answer. When you talk about upgrade the image, I suppose that I have to build it one more time but how can I set the npm version to match it (prefer upgrade than downgrade)?

Comment: ok, so I have downgraded npm ( npm install -g npm@6.14.4 ). the npm -v command confirm the new version but the problem is the same...

Comment: No, npm:6.14.4 is already in the image you're using. You're meant to use a later image (try  node:latest).

Comment: So, in my case it was a little bit more complex. Impossible to update npm due to proxy, some cache in conflict with the new version. But you're both solution helped me a lot and it was exactly the problem. Finally, I've changed the node version for node:latest and now everything is ok. Maybe it could works for node:16.4.2 too! Thanks to both of you for your help, I appreciate guys :)